# Reset timeout duration on command output

Tags: linux, bash, timeout

I have the problem when running a command very irregularly it fails to run.

Currently I am using timeout, but the problem is that when the command does work it takes a long time to finish (several minutes).

Ideally I want to set the timeout to infinity if the command shows some signs of life and keep it 15sec otherwise.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

At the end I solved it by wrapping it up into a python script.
The usage is

```
python script.py [your command]
```

The script will control if the commands needs a re-run

```
import sys
import subprocess
import signal
import time

def handler(signum, frame):
    global atm
    if (atm<3): # attempt to re-run 2 times
        print('re-running')
        atm = atm + 1
        p.kill()
        signal.alarm(0)
        time.sleep(15) # not sure that is needed, but just in case
        run()
    else:
        raise OSError("Number of re-run attempts exceeded")

def run(): # run the command which is passed as a parameter to this script
    global p
    p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler) # will not work on Windows
    signal.alarm(5) # give 5 seconds to produce some output, rerun otherwise
                         
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
        signal.alarm(0) # if output produced remove the alarm
        topr = (line).decode('UTF-8');
        print(topr, end='')

args = sys.argv[1::] # command passed here

atm = 0
run()
```